# How to describe a characters clothing?

Tags: fiction, style, creative-writing, technique, characters

Yeah, So I was bored and decided to write some action Naughty adult fanfic type story today. And then as I started to write I was faced with this issue. How the legit **** am I suppose to describe my character. Like what type of clothes she/he is wearing? What type of Hair Style he/she has? So, How should I describe all of that? Or Should I not bother describing it? But, I kinda do want to describe my characters since there is not much of a plot. I want to focus more on what character wear and how they look. And other crap like that.

For example,

Lets say I want to describe the person in this [pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KyZ9X.jpg). So, how do I describe that character? What level of granularity should I maintain?

I just wanna write a Naughty adult fic about a hot cop chick and become famous.And have the title as *Chick-Merde-Ya*. Help PLz!

Comment: Other questions on the same subject have been asked, take a look at [Importance of clothing description](http://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/12813/is-it-important-to-describe-how-the-characters-are-dressed?rq=1) for example. Also, it's not clear what you're asking, could you boil it down to one single question?

Comment: Agreed, this question needs to be focused so it's asking a specific question, not starting a discussion.

Answer (score 2):

Describe whatever the viewpoint character notices and has opinions about.

In a naughty story, the characters might choose their attire to have certain effects on other people, or to express certain aspects of their attitudes, mood, or desires.

Which means that the characters will have opinions about their attire and the attire of others.

So describe whatever the viewpoint character notices and has an opinion about. And make sure to give the character's opinions.